# Univariate polynomial multiplication using Doubly Linked List

Tags: c, programming-challenge, linked-list

> A univariate polynomial is a polynomial over a single variable, and in
>   the following discussion when we say polynomial, we mean a polynomial
>   in a single variable.  You are given two polynomials – the first one,
>   M1(x), is called the multiplicand, and the second one,  M2(x), is
>   called the  multiplier. Your program has to output the product of
>   M1(x) and M2(x).   You could use the functions implemented in the
>   lectures to maintain your lists corresponding to the polynomials. 
>   Below, you find a formal description of the inputs and outputs.
>
> INPUT & OUTPUT:
>
> The input will be four lines in the format specified below:
>
> Line 1: Number of terms in multiplicand
>    e.g: 2
>
> Line 2: Coefficients and exponents in the multiplicand in the format
>   coeff 1 exp1 coeff2 exp2
>    e.g: 2 2 1 0 which represents 2x^2+1
>
> Line 3: Number of terms in multiplier.
>   e.g: 3
>
> Line 4: Coefficients and exponents in the multiplier in the format
>   coeff 1 exp1 coeff2 exp2 ....
>    e.g: -23 12 11 10 -6 41 which represents -6x^41-23x^12+11x^10
>
> Each line will have multiple sets of coeff exp pairs, each
>   corresponding to a non zero coefficient in the corresponding
>   polynomial. The output has to be a single polynomial in ‘x’ that is
>   the product polynomial. Note that, in the input, for each exponent,
>   there may be multiple terms with the same exponent. However you should
>   print a single term for each exponent while you print the output.
>   Also, if the resulting product is zero, you have to explicitly print a
>   zero.
>
> The output has to be displayed as in the sample output shown with
>   decreasing value of exponent.
>
> Sample Input:
>
> ```
> 2
> 2 1 1 0
> 2
> 3 2 2 0
> ```
>
> Sample Output:
>
> ```
> 6x^3+3x^2+4x+2
> ```

Source : [Please click on this link](http://cprogrammingquest.blogspot.ca/2015/02/polynomial-multiplication.html)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stddef.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct Dcontainer
{
  int coeff;
  int exp;
  struct Dcontainer *prev;
  struct Dcontainer *next;
}DL_node;

void DswapElement(DL_node* position1,DL_node* position2)
{ 
   int etemp,ctemp;
   if((position1 == NULL) || (position2 == NULL)) return;
   etemp = position1->exp;
   ctemp = position1->coeff;
   position1->exp   = position2->exp;
   position1->coeff = position2->coeff;
   position2->exp   = etemp;
   position2->coeff = ctemp;
}

DL_node *Dlast(DL_node* list)
{
  if(list == NULL) return list;
  while(list->next != NULL) 
  {
    list = list->next;
  }
  return list;
}

DL_node * partition(DL_node *l, DL_node *h)
{
    // set pivot as h element
    int x  = h->exp;
    int etemp;
    int ctemp;
    // similar to i = l-1 for array implementation
    DL_node *i = l->prev;
    DL_node *j;
    // Similar to "for (int j = l; j <= h- 1; j++)"
    for (j = l; j != h; j = j->next)
    {
        if (j->exp >= x)
        {
            // Similar to i++ for array
            i = (i == NULL)? l : i->next;
            ctemp    = i->coeff;
            i->coeff = j->coeff;
            j->coeff = ctemp;

            etemp    = i->exp;
            i->exp   = j->exp;
            j->exp   = etemp;
        }
    }
    i = (i == NULL)? l : i->next; // Similar to i++
    DswapElement(i, h);
    return i;
}

/* A recursive implementation of quicksort for linked list */
void _quickSort(DL_node* l, DL_node *h)
{
    if (h != NULL && l != h && l != h->next)
    {
        DL_node *p = partition(l, h);
        _quickSort(l, p->prev);
        _quickSort(p->next, h);
    }
}

// The main function to sort a linked list. It mainly calls _quickSort()
void quickSort(DL_node **poly_head)
{
    // Find last node
    DL_node* h = Dlast(*poly_head);

    // Call the recursive QuickSort
    _quickSort(*poly_head, h);
}

DL_node* DinsertFirst(DL_node** poly_head, int coeff, int exp)
{
   DL_node* new_node = (DL_node*)malloc(sizeof(DL_node));
   new_node->coeff = coeff;
   new_node->exp   = exp;
   new_node->next  = (*poly_head);
   new_node->prev  = NULL;
   if((*poly_head) != NULL) (*poly_head)->prev = new_node;
   (*poly_head) = new_node;
   return *poly_head;
}

void DinsertLast(DL_node** poly_head, int coeff, int exp)
{
   DL_node* new_node = (DL_node*)malloc(sizeof(DL_node));
   DL_node* last     = *poly_head;

   new_node->coeff = coeff;
   new_node->exp   = exp;

   new_node->next  = NULL;

   if(*poly_head == NULL)
   {
      new_node->prev = NULL;
      *poly_head = new_node;
      return;
   }

   while(last->next != NULL)
   {
                last = last->next;
   }

   last->next     = new_node;

   new_node->prev = last;
   return;
}

DL_node* Mul(DL_node* poly1,DL_node* poly2)
{
 DL_node* answer = NULL;
 //DL_node* new_DL_node;
 DL_node* temp   = NULL;
 //DL_node* last   = NULL;
 DL_node* p1temp = poly1;
 DL_node* p2temp = poly2;
 int coeff,exp;
 temp = (DL_node*)malloc(sizeof(DL_node));
 temp->next = NULL;

  while(p1temp != NULL )
  {
       p2temp = poly2;
       while(p2temp != NULL)
       {
          coeff = p1temp->coeff * p2temp->coeff;
          exp   = p1temp->exp    +  p2temp->exp;
          //printf("%d %d \n ",coeff , exp); 
          p2temp = p2temp->next;
          if(answer == NULL)
          {
             answer = DinsertFirst(&answer,coeff,exp);
          }
          else
          {
             DinsertLast(&answer,coeff,exp);
          }  
       }
       p1temp = p1temp->next;
      //printf("%d %d \n ",p1temp->coeff,p1temp->exp); 
  }
  return answer;
}

void Dprint_list(DL_node* poly)
{
  while(poly != NULL)
     {
         printf("%d %d\t ",poly->coeff,poly->exp);
         poly = poly->next;
     }
  printf("\n");      
  return;
}

void Purge(DL_node** poly)
{
   DL_node *cr,*pr,*run,*temp,*del;
   cr   = *poly;
   cr   = cr->next;
   pr   = *poly;
   while(cr != NULL)
   {
       if((*poly)->exp == cr->exp)
       {

           (*poly)->coeff += cr->coeff;
           temp        = cr->prev;
           temp->next  = cr->next;
           (temp->next)->prev = temp;
           del         = cr;
           cr          = cr->next;
           free(del);
       }
       else
       {
           cr  = cr->next;
           pr  = pr->next;
       }
   }
   cr = *poly;
   cr = cr->next;
   pr = *poly;
   while(cr != NULL)
   {
        run = *poly;
        while(run != cr)
        {
          if(run->exp  == cr->exp)
          {
                {
                     run->coeff += cr->coeff;
                }
                temp        = cr->prev;
                temp->next  = cr->next;
                (temp->next)->prev = temp;
                del         = cr;
                cr          = cr->next;
                free(del);
//                pr->next    = cr;
//                cr->prev    = pr;
          }
                run  = run->next;
         }
         if(run == cr)
         {
                cr   = cr->next;
                pr   = pr->next;
         } 
   }
   cr   = *poly;
   cr   = cr->next;
   //printf("%d %d \n", pr->coeff,pr->exp);
   while(cr != NULL)
   {
       if(pr->exp == cr->exp && pr != cr)
       {

           (pr)->coeff += cr->coeff;
           temp        = cr->prev;
           temp->next  = cr->next;
           (temp->next)->prev = temp;
           del         = cr;
           cr          = cr->next;
           free(del);
       }
       else
       {
           cr  = cr->next;
       }
   }
}
void Dprint_list_poly(DL_node* poly)
{
    int flag = 1;  //1 to print +
   int first=0;   
   while(poly != NULL)
     {
         if(poly->coeff !=0)
         {
          if(poly->exp == 0)         
                     {first =1;flag =1;  printf("%d",poly->coeff);}
          else if(poly->exp  == 1 && poly->coeff >1)
                   {first =1 ;flag = 1; printf("%dx",poly->coeff);}
          else if(poly->exp  == 1 && poly->coeff ==1)      
                    {first =1 ;flag = 1; printf("x");}
          else if(poly->coeff == 1)                       
                   {first =1 ;flag =1;  printf("x^%d",poly->exp);}
          else if(poly->coeff < 0 && poly->exp != 1)              
                   {first =1 ;flag = 1; printf("%dx^%d",poly->coeff,poly->exp);}
          else if(poly->coeff < 0 && poly->exp == 1)              
                   {first =1 ;flag = 1; printf("%dx",poly->coeff);}
          else
                   {first =1 ;flag = 1; printf("%dx^%d",poly->coeff,poly->exp);}
          poly = poly->next;
          if((poly)!=NULL && flag == 1 && first == 1 && ((poly->coeff)>0)) printf("+");
         }
         else
         {
             poly = poly->next;
             if(poly != NULL && (poly->coeff)>0 && first == 1) printf("+");
             flag = 0;
         }
      }
   if(flag == 0) printf("0");
   return;

}

int main()
{
  DL_node* poly1 =  NULL;
  DL_node* poly2 =  NULL;
  DL_node* x;
  int terms_1,terms_2;
  char s_1[100];
  char s_2[100];
  int n1,n2;
  int i =0;
  int temp;
  int coeff;
  int exp;
  //char l;
  char delimiters[] = " ";
  char *token;
  int tuple = 1;
  fscanf(stdin,"%d\n", &terms_1);
  n1 = 100;
  fgets(s_1,n1,stdin);
  fscanf(stdin,"%d\n", &terms_2);
  n2 = 100;
  fgets(s_2,n2,stdin);

  token = strtok (s_1, delimiters);      

  while( token != NULL ) 
  {
      //printf( " %s\n", token );
      temp  = atoi(token);
      if(tuple == 1) 
         {
               coeff = temp; 
               tuple++;
         }
         else  
         { 
               exp = temp; 
               tuple--;
               DinsertLast(&poly1, coeff, exp);
         }
         token = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
   }
  i = 0;

  token = strtok (s_2, delimiters);      /* token => "words" */
  while( token != NULL ) 
  {
      // printf( " %s\n", token );
       temp  = atoi(token);
       if(tuple == 1) 
       {
         coeff = temp; 
         tuple++;
       }
       else   
       { 
         exp = temp; 
         tuple--;
         DinsertLast(&poly2, coeff, exp);
       }
     token = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
  }  
   //Dprint_list(poly1);
   x =  Mul(poly1,poly2);
   //Dprint_list(x);
   Purge(&x);
   //Dprint_list(x);
   quickSort(&x);
   //Dprint_list(x);
   Dprint_list_poly(x);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @200_success, I have cited.

Answer (score 1):

On a quick glance,

- You need a function to parse a polynomial. Copy-pasted `while` loop in `main` doesn't look good.
- `quickSort` is under-utilized. Sorting the polynomial by exponents at teh end of `Mul` would simplify `Purge` immensely.
- As coded `Purge` doesn't stand a criticism. A function composed of multiple loops, nested, and apparently (almost) copy-pasted is ill-concieved. Can you state the purpose of each loop?
- `DinsertFirst` communicates the result via return value *and* via the side effect. Do you have a justification for such redundancy? (BTW, `DinsertLast` *only* has side effect; I honestly recommend to stick to return value).
- Each monomial multiplication result is *appended* to the end of list. In other words, the list is traversed N*M times, bringing the complexity to \$O((N*M)^2)\$. *Prepending* results instead is a mere \$O(N*M)\$.

Answer (score 1):

### Printing

To print each term, there are a multitude of considerations:

- If the coefficient is positive, is this the leading term?
- Is this the coefficient ±1, and if so, is it the constant term?
- Is the exponent 0 or 1 or something else?
- If the coefficient is 0, is the polynomial just a monomial?

You have a bit of a **combinatorial explosion of cases** to handle these considerations.  I'm surprised that the code works as well as it does.  It's not quite right, though.  For example, for

```
1
-1 1
1
1 0
```

the result is conventionally rendered as `-x`, but **you print `-1x`**.  Since you have two branches dealing with cases where `poly->coeff == 1`, you would need to add two branches to handle `poly->coeff == -1` as well.  I wonder why your `poly->coeff == 1` tests are placed at the innermost level — this seems like awkward and redundant:

```
if(poly->coeff !=0)
{
  …
  else if(poly->coeff == 1)
           {…}
  …
}
```

All the places where you set `first =1 ;flag =1;` should be factored out.  `first` feels perversely named to me, as it is set to 1 when this is *not* the first term.  `flag` is also a poor variable name, as it provides little insight to its purpose.

### Purging

I'm not sure what you're doing, but having **three loops that all do some variant of `… += cr->coeff;`**, followed by list splicing, makes me suspicious.

When given dubious input, such as a zero-term polynomial…

```
1
1 3
0
0
```

… `Purge()` segfaults attempting to do `cr = cr->next;` on an an empty list.  Admittedly, the input is bad, but it's good practice to avoid crashing nonetheless.

### Use of linked lists

My main criticism, though, is that you used linked lists at all in this solution.  Linked lists come with many disadvantages:

- No random access; you have to traverse them one element at a time.  It's hard to sort a linked list efficiently, for example.
- Memory overhead and fragmentation.  Storing forward and backward pointers already doubles your storage size.  Add to that the space needed by `malloc()` to do its bookkeeping for each tiny allocation.  Making lots of small allocations and deallocations is also leaves your heap in a sorry state.
- There is no built-in support in the C library for linked lists, perhaps due to those issues.  As a result, you end up reinventing the wheel.  Who wants to write, verify, and maintain yet another linked list implementation?  After you've done that exercise once as a beginner, nobody wants to do it again.

There are occasional situations where linked lists may be justified.  This is definitely not one of them, especially since the input format is designed to let you know in advance the size of the inputs, which gives you an upper bound on the size of the result.  You would be much better off using a dynamically sized array — even if it means copy-moving some entries.  (You're already copy-moving entries within your "quicksort" implementation instead of adjusting pointers.  The difference is that list traversal is more cumbersome with linked lists than arrays.)

One strength of linked lists is that you can splice out one element relatively easily.  However, when you coalesce all of the terms of the polynomial with same exponents, you are deleting many elements, and can do so in one pass through the list.  Whether you use an array or linked list, the purge operation is going to be O(*n*), where *n* is the number of terms in the unsimplified representation.  So that justification for linked lists disappears as well.

To illustrate the complication brought about by using linked lists, consider the following solution using dynamic arrays.  Partly because I don't have to write all that linked list support, and can take advantage of the C library's built-in `qsort()`, it's only 1/3 as many lines of code as yours.  It should also perform better, and, in my opinion, it's easier to read.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int coeff;
    int exp;
} Term;

typedef struct {
    size_t len;
    Term *terms;
} Polynomial;

static int term_desc_exp_comparator(const void *term_a, const void *term_b) {
    return ((Term *)term_b)->exp - ((Term *)term_a)->exp;
}

static void canonicalize_polynomial(Polynomial *p) {
    qsort(p->terms, p->len, sizeof(Term), term_desc_exp_comparator);
    size_t out = 0;
    for (size_t in = 1; in < p->len; in++) {
        if (p->terms[out].exp == p->terms[in].exp) {
            p->terms[out].coeff += p->terms[in].coeff;
        } else if (p->terms[out].coeff == 0) {
            p->terms[out] = p->terms[in];
        } else {
            p->terms[++out] = p->terms[in];
        }
    }

    // Zero out the unused terms
    for (size_t i = out + 1; i < p->len; i++) {
        p->terms[i].exp = p->terms[i].coeff = 0;
    }
    p->len = out + 1;
}

Polynomial multiply_polynomials(Polynomial a, Polynomial b) {
    Polynomial prod = {
        .len   = a.len * b.len,
        .terms = malloc(a.len * b.len * sizeof(Term))
    };
    size_t term_ct = 0;

    // Crudely multiply all terms with each other
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.len; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < b.len; j++) {
            prod.terms[term_ct].coeff = a.terms[i].coeff * b.terms[j].coeff;
            prod.terms[term_ct++].exp = a.terms[i].exp   + b.terms[j].exp;
        }
    }

    assert(term_ct == prod.len);
    canonicalize_polynomial(&prod);
    return prod;
}

void print_polynomial(Polynomial p, const char *varname) {
    if (p.len == 0 || (p.len == 1 && p.terms[0].coeff == 0)) {
        puts("0");
        return;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < p.len; i++) {
        switch (p.terms[i].coeff) {
          case 0:
            continue;
          case -1:
            putchar('-');
            if (p.terms[i].exp == 0) putchar('1');
            break;
          case 1:
            if (i) putchar('+');
            if (p.terms[i].exp == 0) putchar('1');
            break;
          default:
            printf(i ? "%+d" : "%d", p.terms[i].coeff);
        }
        switch (p.terms[i].exp) {
          case 0:
            break;
          case 1:
            printf("%s", varname);
            break;
          default:
            printf("%s^%d", varname, p.terms[i].exp);
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

Polynomial input_polynomial() {
    Polynomial p = { .len = 0, .terms = NULL };
    if (scanf("%zd", &p.len) && (p.terms = calloc(p.len, sizeof(Term)))) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < p.len; i++) {
            scanf("%d %d", &p.terms[i].coeff, &p.terms[i].exp);
        }
    }
    return p;
}

void free_polynomial(Polynomial *p) {
    free(p->terms);
    p->terms = NULL;
    p->len = 0;
}

int main() {
    Polynomial a = input_polynomial();
    Polynomial b = input_polynomial();

    Polynomial prod = multiply_polynomials(a, b);
    print_polynomial(prod, "x");

    free_polynomial(&a);
    free_polynomial(&b);
    free_polynomial(&prod);
}
```